# Expression for DateTime::modify() to change day of month

Tags: php, datetime

I have a `DateTime` object and I need to move it to the next day `X` of month. E.g., if `X` is 15:

> 2011-02-03 ⇒ 2011-02-15 # *Earlier than 15, stay on this month*
>
> 2011-02-15 ⇒ 2011-02-15 # *Today's 15, stay on today*
>
> 2011-02-20 ⇒ 2011-03-15 # *Later than 15, move to next month*

I know I can use a combination of `DateTime::format()` and `DateTime::setDate()`, but is it possible to make it **with a single call** to `DateTime::modify()`?

<kbd>!</kbd> It must also work under **`PHP/5.2.14`**.

Expressions that contain "*day 15*" do not even parse.

Comment: Tricky. I am not sure this can be done with a [relative date format](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) alone. It's not worth spending too much time on it when you know how to solve it with a conditional though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$x = 15; // day 15 of the month
$d = $date->format('d');
$m = $date->format('m');
$y = $date->format('Y');

$date->setDate($y , $m , $x); // set the wanted day for the month

//if the wanted day was before the current day, add one month
if( $d > $x ){ // is next month's one.
   $date->modify($date, '+1 month');
}
```

Comment: yeah, as Gordon mentionned, conditional is easier

Comment: It solves my need (+1 for that) but it doesn't really answer my question, which is more on the line of *«can I replace ten lines of spaghetti code with a robust one-liner»* (by spaghetti I mean my code, not yours). I'm trying to improve my skills on relative date formats and I couldn't figure out whether this precise case is achievable.

Comment: Not to my knowledge though. Find anything closer to your need in php documentation? I suppose you've already had a look. If there's nothing there, there's nothing anywhere else.